# Sorting nested Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

My Question is about a sporttable. I'm using different DB Requests to build an array for each team. This looks like:

```
Array(
    [team_id] => 1
    [punkte] => 9
    [fairness] => 5
    [tore_diff] => 3
    [tore_erzielt] => 6
)
```

Now i got 4 or 6 arrays like this for each group. My idea was to put that in a nested array:

Then i got a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 1
            [punkte_s] => 6
            [fairness] => 5
            [tore_diff] => -1
            [tore_erzielt] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 2
            [punkte_s] => 1
            [fairness] => 3
            [tore_diff] => -5
            [tore_erzielt] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 3
            [punkte_s] => 9
            [fairness] => 
            [tore_diff] => 12
            [tore_erzielt] => 15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 4
            [punkte_s] => 1
            [fairness] => 
            [tore_diff] => -6
            [tore_erzielt] => 1
        )

)
```

And so on i try to sort it like this:

```
foreach ($group as $key => $row) {
    $team_id[$key]      =   $row['team_id'];
    $punkte_s[$key]     =   $row['punkte'];
    $fairness[$key]     =   $row['fairness'];
    $tore_diff[$key]    =   $row['tore_diff'];
    $tore_erzielt[$key] =   $row['tore_erzielt'];

};

array_multisort($punkte_s, SORT_DESC, $fairness, SORT_DESC, $tore_diff, SORT_DESC, $tore_erzielt, SORT_DESC, $group);
```

But it doesn't change. Where is my fault?

Comment: 1) array_push does not return array. Just `array_push($group, $team_werte);` does what you want

Comment: 2) to sort resulr array use usrort - http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php or array_multisort - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php. When you will make code and will get any problem return with your questions

Comment: Thanks splash58, i got the multi array with your comment 1 and will try the sort thing and comming back ;-)

Comment: Did you see my edit? May i ask you very nice, if you could help me again?

Comment: create test array on https://eval.in and show the link

Comment: I hardcoded the db result in the array and made the example on: https://eval.in/788796 big thanks for checking it.

Comment: You have typo there - `$punkte_s[$key]     =   $row['punkte'];` shold be ` $row['punkte_s'];`

Comment: YOU made my day!! Thanks so much.. What a stupid misstake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usort()` or `array_multisort()` in a variety of ways.  I'll demonstrate a few.  I like the brevity of the 4th technique, but it requires that your input structure always mirrors the column order that you wish to sort on.

When sorting DESC with `usort()`, write the `$b` values on the left and the `$a` values on the right.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QPbaF))

```
    $array1 = $array2 = $array3 = $array4 = [
        ['team_id' => 1, 'punkte_s' => 6, 'fairness' => 5, 'tore_diff' => -1, 'tore_erzielt' => 6],
        ['team_id' => 2, 'punkte_s' => 1, 'fairness' => 3, 'tore_diff' => -5, 'tore_erzielt' => 2],
        ['team_id' => 3, 'punkte_s' => 9, 'fairness' => null, 'tore_diff' => 12, 'tore_erzielt' => 15],
        ['team_id' => 4, 'punkte_s' => 1, 'fairness' => null, 'tore_diff' => -6, 'tore_erzielt' => 1]
    ];
```

- `array_multisort()` with `array_column()` calls:

  ```
  array_multisort(
      array_column($array1, 'punkte_s'), SORT_DESC,
      array_column($array1, 'fairness'), SORT_DESC,
      array_column($array1, 'tore_diff'), SORT_DESC,
      array_column($array1, 'tore_erzielt'), SORT_DESC,
      $array1
  );

  var_export($array1);
  ```
- `array_multisort()` with a foreach loop:

  ```
  foreach ($array2 as $row) {
      $punkte_s[] = $row['punkte_s'];
      $fairness[] = $row['fairness'];
      $tore_diff[] = $row['tore_diff'];
      $tore_erzielt[] = $row['tore_erzielt'];
  }

  array_multisort(
      $punkte_s, SORT_DESC,
      $fairness, SORT_DESC,
      $tore_diff, SORT_DESC,
      $tore_erzielt, SORT_DESC,
      $array2
  );

  var_export($array2);
  ```
- `usort()` with spaceship operator and explicit array of rules:

  ```
  usort($array3, function($a, $b) {
      return [$b['punkte_s'], $b['fairness'], $b['tore_diff'], $b['tore_erzielt']]
             <=>
             [$a['punkte_s'], $a['fairness'], $a['tore_diff'], $a['tore_erzielt']];
  });

  var_export($array3);
  ```
- `usort()` with spaceship operator with reliance on input array column structure:

  ```
  usort($array4, function($a, $b) {
      unset($a['team_id'], $b['team_id']);
      return $b <=> $a;
  });

  var_export($array4);
  ```